# Error to open design Theme: Content-->Design-->Configuration?

Tags: magento2, error

When I try to open `Content-->Design-->Configuration` and click on edit, it came up with below error.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Can't create
>   directory
>   /home/tassosco/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Theme/Model/Design/Backend/Favicon/.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: give writable permission to var directory

Comment: var directory permission is 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments you need to set proper permission for your `var/generation` folder. This is also given in the official documentation too.

As you can see in the error, Magento is trying to generate some files on the fly and it cannot create the file some how (this is most probably due to permission issue).

Either the apache user/command line user do not have the privilege to create files or folders or the permission to the `var/generation` folder is not 755. You need to make sure these two conditions are configured correctly in your M2 instance.

Please see below docs for your reference.

- [Set ownership and permission in M2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)
- [Cannot write to the var/generation directory](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_var-gen-perms.html)